# Como devem ser armazenados os dados de uma rota?

Tags: mobile, geolocalização

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação onde será iniciado uma rota do ponto `A` ao `B` e desejo salvar as coordenadas para exibir a rota posteriormente.

Como devem ser salvos esses dados? Monitorar quaisquer mudanças no `GPS` e salvar a **latitude** e **longitude** e montar um grande `array` ou `json`?

Há alguma padrão a ser seguido para esse tipo de informação?

Comment: De fato, esse seria uma possibilidade: gravar inicialmente um log de cada uma das coordenadas visitadas, para depois fazer um pós-processamento em cima das coordenadas.

Comment: Caso esteja usando o Google Maps, este post lista algumas das possibilidades: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711468/create-a-route-using-a-list-of-coordinates-in-google-maps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Salve os dados em uma tabela de banco de dados ou json em arquivo, como preferir.
Mas você precisa ter a hora em que foi registrado e a posição para poder traçar a rota.

É preciso definir um  intervalo de tempo ou distância para ser gravado, por exemplo a cada 5 metros ou 1min você salva a posição.

Exemplo.

[image: exemplo]

O padrão a ser seguido depende da necessidade de traçar a rota... Os mais usados para rastreio. é por exemplo: caso a posição de afaste mais de 5 metros, ele registra a mudança, lembrando que é preciso definir um raio para tolerância, já q o GPS nem sempre mantem a precisão.

Na imagem postada a todo momento eu registrava a posição, então mesmo parado no mesmo lugar o GPS retornava valores diferentes, não tratei tolerância e nem distância da antiga posição.